# How to set filename for presigned_url in s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I am using amazon sdk version 2

For presigned_url i use the below
url = signer.presigned_url(:get_object, bucket: bucket, key: key)

But how do i set the filename?( For users when they select save as..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to add response_content_disposition and set the filename

signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new
signer.presigned_url(:get_object, bucket: bucket, key: key, response_content_disposition: "attachment;filename=test.pdf")

Comment: FYI, setting the content disposition to attachment will tell the browser to download the file instead of rendering it if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you add ${filename} to the key it will be replaced with the filename chosen when uploading the file.

Comment: does not work with safari but works with firefox and chrome